# Remove HTML tag from rss input logstash plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash-rss-input plugin to index rss feeds in elasticsearch, but I get text and html tag, whic I just want to get text not html tag.
any one can say me which filter plugin should I use and how to filter it ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Logstash what about the [xml plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-filters-xml.html) :

```
filter {
  xml {
    source => "my_source"
    #other configs, see the doc
  }
}
```

Comment: The xml filter will let me extract the article text but it'll still contain HTML markup

Comment: what about html_strip ?

Comment: It depends if you prefer to filter the rss feed from logstash, or defer the filtering to elastic search mainly.

Comment: If you please provide some example how to remove HTML markup with logstash-filter-xml